# TSQL Trigger unknown Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, compare

I have a table which have 31 Columns
PrimaryField,PersNr, a1, a2, a3, a4, ...
in the a1 - a31 fields are values. The software generate automaticly each month one row. 
The user can now from the software update a field or delete it (Update to NULL).

But now I need a Trigger which make an insert in a new table for each **changed** field. The Problem is the comparison from the before row and the changed row. How can I get the changed field when the User Update the Row?

Comment: You can you an instead of trigger. Then you can compare the values in the table (old) with inserted (new). You will then have to use the inserted to carry on the insert as using an instead of would halt it.

Comment: Ideally, you change the table design. Data of the same "type" ought to be stored in the *same* column. Add an extra column so that the day numbers, currently embedded in column names, can actually take their place rightfully in the *data*. Leave pivotting of the data into a spreadsheet layout to your report processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can run that should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName --The name of your trigger
ON Table1 --The table where the update happens

AFTER UPDATE 

AS
INERT INTO --you new tabe namegoes here
()--your new table fields go here

SELECT --only the fields you have in the parenthesis above in the same order 
FROM Inerted I
```

The way most triggers are is that as soon as a value is inseted updated or deleted the trigger has a special vlaue in this case fr update and inserted actions the table is called Inserted and that will grab the most current value entered.

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL Server trigger, you have access to `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables; those keep the data that has been modified: the first one stores the new values, the second the old ones.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTableUpdate
ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN

IF NOT UPDATE (a1) AND NOT UPDATE(a2) AND NOT UPDATE(a3) AND NOT UPDATE...
    RETURN

SELECT YourCOlumns FROM Inserted 
SELECT YourColumsn FROM Deleted

--Compare the values as you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me.
In the morning when I stand up I got an Idea :)

The point was:
1. DECLARE AND Set Variables:

```
DECLARE @ai1 VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @ad1 VARCHAR(30);
....
SET @ai1 = (SELECT a1 from inserted);
SET @ad1 = (SELECT a1 from deleted);
...
```

2. To Compare every @ai and @ad

   IF NOT @ai1 = @ad1 OR (@ai1 IS NULL AND @ad1 IS NOT NULL) OR (@ai1 IS NOT NULL AND @ad1 IS NULL)
   BEGIN 
   ... Insert...
   END
   IF NOT @ai2 = @ad2...

Thats the Trick. But thank you all very much!!!

Comment: And that's a broken trigger. `inserted` and `deleted` may contain 0, 1, or *multiple* rows. In the latter case, you're not even guaranteed that `@ai1` and `@ad1` have been assigned values from the "same" before/after row.